# error ID 486 (source ID 239) when adding a participant to Lync conversation

Tags: lync-2013

**I am running Lync 2013 client on Windows 7, connecting to a Lync 2013 Server.**

When attempting to add a participant to a Lync conversation, the invitee is added to the conversation's `Participants` list, but after a few seconds is removed and I receive the following message:

```
An error occurred.
When contacting your support team, reference error ID 486 (source ID 239).

Troubleshooting information is available online, including best practices for using Lync.

Learn More
```

The user I attempted to invite never receives a call.

The "Learn More" text is a link which sends to :
http://r.office.microsoft.com/r/rlidUCErr10?clid=1033&p1=0&p2=29&p3=141&p4=141&p5=141&p6=141
This address is in turn forwarded to:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Generic-Error-b5517285-d4e0-4a92-a58b-96a066d9f3c9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

This page is a reference for "Generic Error" in **Lync 2010**...

I can find no information on this error anywhere... What does this error mean?
Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means : ["Cannot reach [user name]. Try again later."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg132389(v=office.12).aspx)

When you try add this participant, can you verify is there any local extension or PSTN number associated with him. because some times when you try to call Lync to Lync it gets forward to his extension or PSTN number.

But you could try to get help from your [support team](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/gp_lync_main).